# Is it permissible to marry someone with whom you have had premarital sex?

Tags: sharia, nikah, fiqh, zina

I have had sex with an innocent girl of my age we both are muslims. I did not have the knowledge of haram and halal while performing the act but now I feel disgusted. She wants me to marry her but my parents are strictly against love marriges.

Question: I want to know if this relationship would be halal if i convince my parents to get us married?

I am afraid if this relationship would become haram as we have already indulged in the sinful act. I am very scared and I do not want to spoil her future. Please guide me in this as I do not want to let her go.

Answer (score 4):

Majority opinion is that it is permissible to marry the person with whom one has committed *Zina*, provided that the person is not a habitually unchaste person and that they both sincerely repent of their sin and that a period equal to *iddah* has passed since the unlawful intercourse.

> إنّ من زنى بامرأة فله أن يتزوجها ولغيره أن
>   يتزوّجها
>
> وهو قول ابن عمر وسالم وجابر بن زيد وعطاء وطاوس ومالك بن أنس، وهو قول
>   أبي حنيفة وأصحابه. وقال الشافعيّ: القول فيها كما قال سعيد بن المسيّب
>
> One who commits fornication with a woman. It is permissible for him to
>   marry her and it is also permissible for another man to marry her.
>
> And this is the saying of Ibn Umar, Salim, Jabir bin Zayed, Ata,
>   Tawus, Malik bin Anas. And the same is the saying of Abu Hanifa and
>   his companions. And from Shafi is narrated the same as that of Saeed bin Musaib [ it is permissible since a fornicator is part of the unmarried Muslim community viz [24:32](https://quran.com/24/32) ]
>
> وقال ابن عباس: أوله سفاح وآخره نكاح. ومَثَلُ ذلك مَثَلُ رجل سَرَق من
>   حائط ثمره ثم أتى صاحب البستان فاشترى منه ثمره؛ فما سَرَق حرام وما
>   اشترى حلال
>
> Ibn Abbas said [about a person who married a woman he had fornicated with], his beginning was fornication and ending was marriage. His example is like that of a person who steals from a garden and then goes to the owner to buy what he stole. What he stole was haram and what he bought is halal.
>
> [Tafsir Qurtubi](http://www.altafsir.com/Tafasir.asp?tMadhNo=0&tTafsirNo=5&tSoraNo=24&tAyahNo=3&tDisplay=yes&Page=2&Size=1&LanguageId=1)

Also relevant:

https://islamqa.info/en/96460
http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=343603

Comment: can you please answer this zina related question: https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/43796/18985

Comment: @HammadNasir The Tafsir I've quoted above answers that as well, its permissible for her to marry any Muslim, the Zani or otherwise  ولغيره أن يتزوّجها